# HttpContext.RewritePath() from HTTP module yields 403 forbidden

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, httpmodule

I'd like to use the following HTTP module to rewrite a request to another folder's file:

```
public class MyHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        application.BeginRequest += (sender, e) =>
            {
                var httpApplication = (HttpApplication)sender;
                var httpContext = httpApplication.Context;

                if (httpContext.Request.Url.ToString().Contains("styles/style.css"))
                {
                    httpContext.RewritePath("~/some/other/folder/styles/style.css");
                }
            };
    }

    public void Dispose() { }
}
```

The code seems to work as expected (i.e. after `RewritePath()` `Request.Url` contains the rewritten URL) but I get a 403.2 forbidden error when I try to open styles/style.css.

When I open the rewritten URL (taken from `Request.Url` after the `RewritePath()` call) in a browser I correctly see the CSS file (i.e. I open something like styles/style.css and get what's under some/other/folder/styles/style.css).

Failed Request Tracing also shows that my module does the correct rewrite. This the trace entry corresponding to the error:

```
82.  -NOTIFY_MODULE_END
ModuleName ManagedPipelineHandler 
Notification MAP_REQUEST_HANDLER 
fIsPostNotificationEvent false 
NotificationStatus NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE 

83.  -MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS 
ModuleName IIS Web Core 
Notification MAP_REQUEST_HANDLER 
HttpStatus 403 
HttpReason Forbidden
HttpSubStatus 2 
ErrorCode Access is denied. (0x80070005) 

84.  -SECURITY_DENIED_BY_ACCESS_FLAGS 
CurrentFlags 512 
NeededFlags 1
```

As far as I can tell it requires AccessRead (1) permissions but got AccessScript (512) (see [this topic](http://forums.iis.net/t/1160629.aspx)). This puzzles me because I guess the latter is a higher permission level than the former.

Changing file system permissions on the folder of the file in question doesn't seem to have an effect (even giving full control to Everyone won't help). The app pool is using my user, an admin account, as its identity (but leaving it on AppPoolIdentity isn't helping either).

The file's folder has a Web.config that contains this if it matters:

```
<handlers accessPolicy="Script,Read">
  <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
</handlers>
```

Doing the same rewrite with the IIS URL Rewrite module works.

**Update:**

I noticed that creating a physical folder under the original, not existing path (i.e. ~/styles/style.css), just containing a Web.config with the above handler declaration (plus the common ceremony around it with system.webServer etc.) makes the error go away. Naturally this is not a solution for me but at least it gives some hint.

**Update2:**

I did some tests with an empty ASP.NET app. Setting up only the module in the root Web.config and not adding a Web.config to the Styles folder worked.

Adding this to the root Web.config (this is something from the original app's Web.config) caused the error. Ha!

```
<handlers accessPolicy="Script">
  <clear />
</handlers>
```

Modifying the accessPolicy to "Script, Read". Resolved the issue...

Could somebody explain this please?

Comment: Could you provide a repro which doesn't make use of Orchard, I could share the solution with someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to have a web.config in "some" folder [~/some/other/folder/styles/style.css] and delete all web.config files at its subfolders. In the only web.config you may try this:

```
<handlers accessPolicy="Script,Read">
  <!--
  iis7 - for any request to a file exists on disk, return it via native http module.
  accessPolicy 'Script' is to allow for a managed 404 page.
  -->

  <add name="StaticFileHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule,DirectoryListingModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" />
</handlers>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this yields the same. The "some" folder now only contains subfolders of this path, and the single styles.css with the Web.config (tried the original one, tried yours) so supposedly there is nothing else interfering.